# Pointer Initialization Issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to initialize a null pointer by passing it to a function and then calling `new` I created two functions for the purpose:

```
void Create1(int** temp)
{
    *temp = new int(10);
}

void Create2(int *temp)
{
    temp = new int(10);
}

int main()
{
    int *data_1 = NULL;
    int *data_2 = NULL;
    Create1(&data_1);
    Create2(data_2);
}
```

Why is that the Create1 function properly initializes data_1 but Create2 function fails to initialize data_2 ?

Comment: Because `Create2` assigns its allocation to an local variable that is lost as soon as the function returns. Try `int *& temp` for the parameter type (a reference to a pointer).

Comment: I would return the pointer from your function rather than modify a parameter.

Comment: If we're suggesting alternatives Neil, we should be suggesting `shared_ptr` and friends, not different ways to use raaw pointers!

Comment: how do you check that it failed to initialize the pointer? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass by reference to get the behavior you're looking for:

```
void Create2(int * &temp)
{
    temp = new int(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create1 passes a pointer to a pointer so when you defer it you are actually assigning to the passed pointer, create2 is assigning it to a local variable that gets out of scope at the end of the function block thus the new operation assign new memory in the free store, which is pointed by no one, thus creating a memory leak, to solve this pass a reference to a pointer to create2 "int* &temp" this way the value gets actually assigned to the passed pointer

Answer (score 1):

This is because Create1 receives a location where to write the new pointer value, while the Create2 receives a null pointer and modifications inside Create2 only modify the local variable used to hold that null pointer without affecting anything outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because on the second case you are passing the value of a pointer to it.  Even if you change its value, that change doesn't get passed back to the caller.  You are effectively making a copy of its value.

On the first case you are passing the address where the pointer resides.  You are writing to that location something.  When the caller runs it can see what you placed there.  You are telling it where something resides.  That location is common to both caller and callee.